# Shred memory between Tornado processes

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, tornado

I have a Tornado server just for websocket. There I defined a global dictionary for storing connected users.

```
...
# Global dictionary
client_dict = {}

class MessagesHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    ...
    def open(self, v):
        ...
        # Put {user_id: self} that it will able to send message somebody  
        # And make sure that there are no copy of self 
        if self.user_id in client_dict:
            is_self_not_there = True
            for i in client_dict[self.user_id].values():
                if i is self:
                    is_self_not_there = False
            if is_self_not_there:
                client_dict[self.user_id].update({max(client_dict[self.user_id], key=int)+1:self})
        else:
            client_dict.update({self.user_id : {0:self}})

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, mess):
        ...
        # send mesage to certain user
        for k, recipient_wsconnection in client_dict[recipient_id].items():
            recipient_wsconnection.write_message('Ko ko ko')
    ...
...
```

It worked fine when I launch it just one process.

But I want to use supervisord in production that launch several instances on different ports. And proxy these instances through nginx to the Internet. I decided to do that just for load balancing.

As you can see there are several instances and each instance has an own independent dictionary (client_dict).

I had an idea to serialize (via pickle) each user (an instance of MessagesHandler) and store it in Redis. But when I deserialize it, it becomes a copy of already existing object.

Is there a way to have shared memory and store a global dictionary there?

Or maybe there is another way of load balancing of my Tornado server?

Maybe [Consistent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) could help me, but I don't quite understand how implement it...

Comment: maybe use a cache like redis